# C++ atomic increment memory ordering

Tags: c++, c++11, atomic

In C++11:
If I increment an atomic variable (operator ++ on std::atomic), is the new value stored with a memory barrier? Or do I have to explicitly do a store?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't need to do an explicit store. The sequential consistency memory ordering will be used.

`operator++(int)` and `operator++()` on `atomic<`*`integral`*`>` types are specified to have the effect of `fetch_add(1)`, which ends up calling the member function with the default memory ordering `memory_order_seq_cst`.

For the spec look around *Requirements for operations on atomic types* [atomics.types.operations.req] 29.6.5/33

Comment: ok I see...I missed the default of memory_order_seq_cst for fetch_add..thanks